# Multipivot issue in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Unable to use multi column pivot in Snowflake. Single column pivot is working fine.
Below is my Query:

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT geo_lkp.MSA_CD , geo_lkp.MSA_NM, geo_lkp.CSA_CD , 
    geo_lkp.CSA_NM
    FROM T_GEO_LKP geo_lkp , T_DIM_STATE_PROV state_lkp 
    WHERE geo_lkp.state_prov_nm = state_lkp.state_prov_cd 
    AND UPPER(geo_lkp.PSTL_CD) = '12345' AND state_lkp.ISO_3_CHAR_CNTRY_CD = 'USA' ) 
    
    UNPIVOT( (LOCATION_CODE, LOCATION_NAME) FOR LOCATION_TYPE
            IN ( (CSA_CD,CSA_NM) AS 'csa', 
                 (MSA_CD,MSA_NM) AS 'msa') )
                ORDER BY LOCATION_NAME
```

trying to convert below table data :

| MSA_CD | MSA_NM | CSA_CD | CSA_NM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10580 | Albany | 104 | Albany |

to

| LOCATION_TYPE | LOCATION_CD | LOCATION_NM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| msa | 10580 | Albany |
| csa | 104 | Albany |

Comment: Oracle is not Snowflake.  I removed the irrelevant tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From snowflake support we came to know that multi column UNPIVOT is not supported right now. We have to do work around. One can be as mentioned by @gordon Linoff.

Another solution can be:

```
with location_data as (
    SELECT DISTINCT geo_lkp.MSA_CD , geo_lkp.MSA_NM, geo_lkp.CSA_CD ,
    geo_lkp.CSA_NM
    FROM T_GEO_LKP geo_lkp , T_DIM_STATE_PROV state_lkp
    WHERE geo_lkp.state_prov_nm = state_lkp.state_prov_cd
    AND UPPER(geo_lkp.PSTL_CD) = '12345' AND state_lkp.ISO_3_CHAR_CNTRY_CD = 'USA' 
    )
select location_type, location_code, location_name from
(
  select 'csa' as location_type, csa_cd as location_code, csa_nm as location_name from location_data
  union all
  select 'msa', msa_cd, msa_nm from location_data
) where location_code is not null order by location_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a lateral join and `values`:

```
select v.*
from t cross join lateral
     (values ('msa', msa_cd, msa_nm),
             ('csa', csa_cd, csa_nm)
     ) v(location_type, location_cd, location_nm)
```